# Can't popup modal in the fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, popup, fullcalendar, event-calendar

I have a problem creating a popup modal in the full calendar function. I using this code to let the modal box popup  `$('#createEventModal').modal('toggle');`, but it cannot work. Below is my coding.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='fullcalendar/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='fullcalendar/main.js'></script>
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      initialDate: '2021-04-25',
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      selectable: true,
      selectMirror: true,
      
      
      select: function(arg) {                
                $('#createEventModal #startTime').val(arg.start);
                $('#createEventModal #endTime').val(arg.end);
                $('#createEventModal #when').text(arg.start);
                $('#createEventModal').modal('toggle');
           },
      eventClick: function(arg) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this event?')) {
          arg.event.remove()
        }
      },
      editable: true,
      dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: [
        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2020-09-01'
        },
        {
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: '2020-09-07',
          end: '2020-09-10'
        },
        {
          groupId: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2020-09-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          groupId: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2020-09-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Conference',
          start: '2020-09-11',
          end: '2020-09-13'
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2020-09-12T10:30:00',
          end: '2020-09-12T12:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Lunch',
          start: '2020-09-12T12:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2020-09-12T14:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Happy Hour',
          start: '2020-09-12T17:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Dinner',
          start: '2020-09-12T20:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Birthday Party',
          start: '2020-09-13T07:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Click for Google',
          url: 'http://google.com/',
          start: '2020-09-28'
        }
      ]
    });

    calendar.render();
  });

</script>
<style>

  body {
    margin: 40px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  #calendar {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id='calendar'></div>

    <!-- Modal -->
<div id="createEventModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Event</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputPatient">Event:</label>
                <div class="field desc">
                    <input class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Event" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <input type="hidden" id="startTime"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="endTime"/>
            
            
       
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="when">When:</label>
            <div class="controls controls-row" id="when" style="margin-top:5px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton">Save</button>
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.

I want the expected popup modal like below the picture:

[image: output1]

Comment: Hi, its working just fine . Did you add bootstrap files in your page ? Also , check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ou2knybm/) working code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try it first.

Comment: @Swati You are right. You save my day. Thanks.